# Auto include/compile source codes using folder reference in XCode4

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In XCode4, when we add a new folder which is a folder reference under the Resource folder, the images found under this folder will be automatically copies to the device, no need to add them one by one.

How about for source code?
Is it possible to create a folder reference for the Classes folder, so when I add new source files under this folder in the file system, it will automatically compiled and linked?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, something new in a referenced folder doesn't trigger the routine to add the .m file to the Compile Sources build phase, because a folder itself cannot be in that phase. A referenced folder in the resource folder is copied recursively.

Comment: I am following method like: http://majicjungle.com/blog/123/, ok for resources, but not works for codes.

Comment: Ah I think I understood your question now completely.